# Polymer - Drop Down Style

Tags: css, polymer

I'm working on a Polymer app. In this app, I have a `paper-dropdown-menu` that is defined like this:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu id="foodMenu" label="Choose an item" no-label-float="true">
  <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item>Croissant</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Donut</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Financier</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Madeleine</paper-item>
  </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

By default, the label color is gray. Then, when a user chooses an item, the chosen item is shown as black. I am trying to style the control such that both of the label and the selected item are white. However, I'm not having any luck. Currently, I've defined the following style:

```
#foodMenu {
  --paper-input-container-underline: {
    display: none;
  }
}

#foodMenu paper-input {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Unfortunately, that approach does not work. Yet, I'm not sure what to do. How do I make the label and selected text up as white?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try styling the `<paper-item>` element instead, since the dropdown is composed of these elements.

Example:

```
paper-dropdown-menu paper-item {
  --paper-item-selected-weight : 400;
  --paper-item-focused-before: {
    background: #fff;
  };
}
```

I created a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sZyQwtTeQVAZi7ozkRPM?p=preview).

More Info about `<paper-item>` [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-item).

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. The text is still gray. I confirmed this by forking your plunk and setting the background-color to black as shown here: http://plnkr.co/edit/aChII6zSWCPNZAcqiAWc?p=preview

Comment: you set the `background-color` inline style for the `paper-dropdown-menu`, try playing around with the `paper-item` `backgroud` property instead. You wanted to hide/paint white the selected item background color didn't you? or may you explain me better what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I set the background-color just to show my issue. I am trying to set the color of the label. In other words, I am trying to make the word "Food" in my plunk white. "Food" is the label that appear is nothing is selected. If a user chooses "Donut", the word "Donut" appears below the word "Food". I want the word "Donut" to be white. Does that make sense?  I'm really struggling to get this styled correctly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/PZ95m7IPlbVxlMIvSx92?p=preview. I used `--paper-input-container-input`, `--paper-input-container-label` and `--paper-input-container-underline` selectors.

Comment: Yes! That's what I was trying to do. thank you so much for your help!